# Is it possible to add custom cdn module in advagg module for Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, advagg

I am using `Drupal 7` and installed the [advagg](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) module. There is an option for CDN integration for both css and js. But no configurations available for them. After some digging I found a [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/advanced-cssjs-aggregation/advanced-aggregates-cdn) for Drupal 8. It is mention that the CDN will work for Jquery and Jquery UI from google cdn.

My question is, **is it possible to add a custom cdn with this cdn property of advagg module?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cdn](https://www.drupal.org/project/cdn) module to achieve this

Comment: Thank u, Already using this. But sometimes it is causing issues with css. Updating the variable table triggering frequently and that making the site slow at times.